# Move Git commits to a directory

Tags: git, directory, commit, rebase

I have 4 repositories, each one with the source code of a module of the system.

Now, I want to join all them in a single repository preserving history. But, in this four repos, the code is in the root folder and in the new repo I need to put each module in it's own subfolder.

I would like that, in the history, it looks like the commits were always made in the subfolders. Something like "rebase all commits inside a folder".

Answer (score 2):

There is something like that, it is called `git submodule`.